# Which files to edit in a processed CMS website?

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, themes, modx

I am trying to edit a processed cms (modx) created website. From my customer I only received the ftp logins not the modx account for some reasons. Now I struggled myself for 4-5 days to find out how to edit that website. I downloaded the public_html that is the only file I have access to. So here I am I was looking through all the files for finding out where is the html file.[html files location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP2IN.png)
But unfortunately, after I edit the file nothing is saved. The only thing I have to change is a link for a button but it doesn't save. I tried to edit each of these files but it doesn't save at all. I was wondering if should I change something in a php file or if I am editing the right files.
[script way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmwFy.png)
[href way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyfDZ.png)
What am I doing wrong? I am tired of running around the same files.
Thank you

1. List item

Comment: Being asked to change a CMS-driven website with no access to the CMS is kinda crazy. In most of them, there won't **be** a file for a particular page to edit; it's usually stored in a database somewhere.

Comment: Somehow I also find out the database logins:))))  looking through php files so I also have access to that. But not sure what to change there, I have seen some html snippets @ceejayoz

Comment: Rather than wasting another 4-5 days, **ask your client for an account.**

Comment: So basically there is no way to do it like that? because I wondered if I have an html file and just save it, it will work, is because of php why it doesn't save?